# python: Is dot notation deprecated?

Tags: python-3.x, python-import, relative-import

Today I got email with feedback from my recruitment task. One of the notices said:

> There was usage of dot notation which is deprecated (`from .bfs import BFS`)

The code that is quoted comes from my **init**.py module, and the project tree goes like this:

```
my-app/
├─ main.py/
├─ src/
│  ├─ __init__.py
│  ├─ bfs.py
├─ .gitignore
├─ requirements.txt
├─ README.md
etc...
```

Question is: Is there a better way to use **init**.py file? Is "dot notation" really deprecated?

Comment: use the path: `from src/bfs import BFS`

Comment: @DL so better have a syntax error in your opinion?

Comment: There is absolutely nothing wrong with using the relative import as long as you run your code from the my-app dir using the -m switch - still how are you. importing in main.py?

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D yes.

Comment: Except if you are using the `__name__ == '__main__'` - then you should use absolute imports - _how are you importing in main.py?_